# Calculate DateTime difference in query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table in which i have START_DATE column which is DATE datatype. I want to get all the SUBSCRIPTION_ID which is older than the last 30 min from the current datetime.
Here is my query:

```
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,WF.START_DATE
   from WF_WORKFLOW
   where WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0
```

Comment: WHERE START_DATE < sysdate-((1/24/60)*30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend the `where` clause with another condition:

```
start_date < sysdate - 30 / (24 * 60)
```

Oracle interprets a date as a number of days value.  So, 30 minutes is `30 / (24 * 60)`.

Comment: Hello Gordon thank you :) it works. Just a small question. I have another query in which i want SUBSCRIPTION_ID  which have START_DATE for last 24 hour . How can i do that ?

Comment: 24 hour is actually just : 1. --- So, `sysdate - 1` is exactly 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [INTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598)

So this might work,

```
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,WF.START_DATE
   from WF_WORKFLOW
   where WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0 and WF.START_DATE < sysdate - INTERVAL '30' minute(1)
```

Comment: DATEADD appears to be a SQL server function, he question is tagged as Oracle. Probably doesn't help. ;)

Comment: It works :) Just a small question. I have another query in which i want SUBSCRIPTION_ID which have START_DATE for last 24 hour . How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
     , WF.START_DATE
  from WF_WORKFLOW
 where WF.NAME='SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID' 
   and WF.STATUS_ID=0
   and WF.START_DATE + TO_DSINTERVAL('000 00:30:00') < SYSDATE
     ;
```